# What is the meaning of "pants time" in this review title?

Tags: meaning

The title is: *'Great Little War Game 2' Review - **Pants Time** Is Extended One Final Round* And here's a link to the full article: http://toucharcade.com/2014/06/16/great-little-war-game-2-review/

Comment: The amazing thing about our modern age is that sometimes you can [ask the author](https://twitter.com/TyJaYo/status/479264350008778753) and if you're lucky enough, you might get a reply ;)

Comment: So this is the best reply I could get. Now, everything is clear, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A character in the game occasionally appears in just his General's hat and his boxer underpants.  He refers to this as "pants time".

Worth noting that the game's developer is from the UK and uses UK English, where 'pants' refers to underwear and not trousers, as it does in US English.

Comment: Just don't tell me that you're the author of this review. :)